# Can I stream a file to a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, file-upload, filestream

I have a file on a remote machine that I want to 'copy' to the SQL Server host machine to a specific area. I'm wondering what my options are for doing this through a SQL Server stored procedure, and more specifically I want to stream the file contents, not reading the entire contents into memory first.

I'm basically looking for a streamed version of this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveFile]
    (@filename nvarchar(255), @contents nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'WriteText', NULL, @contents
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, 'C:\\Destination\\' + @filename, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
END
```

1. Can I have a `filestream` or something equivalent as a stored procedure input parameter?
2. Have a CLR stored procedure handle the stream?
3. Perhaps one procedure could open the stream and return the `@ObjectToken`, another could `WriteText` a chunk from the stream, and a third procedure could `SaveToFile` and `Close` it, but this seems like `!a.GoodIdea` and I'd have to ensure closure and destruction through some sort of timeout.
4. Other options?

It's being sourced from a C# console application and I'd prefer to stream these large files instead of something like `File.ReadAllText()`, loading a multi-gigabyte string into a variable, and then calling a stored procedure with the entire contents of the file.

Comment: my two cents, get an Azure account and use their storage API.

Comment: Azure cloud storage is not even a remote possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few attempts to get this working with OLE Automation (`sp_OACreate`, `sp_OAMethod`, etc.) and ran into a number of issues and made a CLR-based solution.

I have a C# console application, C# CLR Stored Procedures and a sample SQL Server database posted on [my github account](https://github.com/Ehryk) in repository named [StreamFile](https://github.com/Ehryk/StreamFile).

The basic idea is that I call a procedure to initiate the transfer which logs a row in the database and creates the file, send `n` chunks to a different stored procedure that appends to the file, and then call a third stored procedure to denote the successful completion of streaming.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StreamFile_AddBytes]
    (@fileID int, @chunk varbinary(max))
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @tmppath nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @tmppath = FilePath FROM StreamedFiles WHERE StreamedFileID = @fileID

    IF (@tmppath is null)
        RAISERROR (N'Invalid StreamedFileID Provided: %d', 11, 1, @fileID);

    --C# CLR Based Stored Procedure
    EXEC dbo.AppendBytes @tmppath, @chunk

    UPDATE StreamedFiles SET Chunks = Chunks + 1, FileSize = FileSize + LEN(@chunk) WHERE StreamedFileID = @fileID

    SELECT * FROM StreamedFiles sf WHERE sf.StreamedFileID = @fileID
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution that I will be testing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StreamOpen]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    SELECT @ObjectToken
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StreamAddChunk] (@token int, @chunk nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'WriteText', NULL, @contents
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StreamClose] (@token int, @filename nvarchar(260))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'WriteText', NULL, @contents
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'SaveToFile', NULL, 'C:\\Destination\\' + @filename, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @token
END
```

I will update this answer once it is tested, and add the C# calling code.

Comment: This does not work, as all OLE objects are destroyed at the end of the batch.